# Any built in methods where I can get the UNIX server manufacturer / model and serial number?

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script that will be deployed and executed on many servers. Some of my requirements are retrieving the manufacturer, model and serial number. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I'm not seeing any built in libraries to do this.

I'm not sure if I can use libraries that don't come with Perl since I wouldn't be able to include those when it gets executed on the other servers.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything else then what you can get from `uname -a`

Comment: Concur. Completely platform-dependent.

Comment: Not sure about that. See below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a perl module called [`Parse::DMIDecode`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse::DMIDecode) which will use the dmidecode program that Brian pointed out.

Comment: Completely overlooked this when I was diving into the perldocs. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's not Perl but you can invoke

```
$ sudo dmidecode
```

from within your script. That will dump the BIOS info and on my machine I get:

```
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP xw6600 Workstation
    Version:  
    Serial Number: CXC9062H43
    UUID: 53F3EB48-4CF9-DD11-BBDA-29023A11001F
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: RV725AV
    Family: 103C_53335X
```

I don't know how much of the above is a) standard info b) populated by our service desk when provisioning PCs for our use. But it's worth investigating further.

From the man page for `dmidecode`:

> dmidecode  is  a  tool  for  dumping  a  computer's DMI (some say
>   SMBIOS) table contents in a human-readable format. This table contains
>   a
>          description of the system's hardware components, as well as other useful pieces of information such as serial numbers and  BIOS 
>   revision.
>          Thanks  to  this  table, you can retrieve this information without having to probe for the actual hardware.  While this is a good
>   point in
>          terms of report speed and safeness, this also makes the presented information possibly unreliable